# Is there a compression format that allows update content inplace?

Tags: zip, compression, gzip, tar, 7zip

`zip` format does not allow in-place update. To replace a file in zip, one must make a copy of the original zip file and copy those files unchanged as long as the updated file to a new zip file.

Others, like tar.gz, do not allow inplace replacement, either,

Is there a compression format that allows in-place update natively?

I am not sure about 7z. Is anybody familar with it?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Linux or Mac OS.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an appropriate type of question for this website. StackOverflow is about code.

Comment: Then put it in another way. What code is allowed to change an archive in-place?

Comment: Well... This site is **purely** about problems with source code, errors, invocations and etc... You're asking about features of a softwere, or a software recomendation.  This type of question should be asked here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or in some cases here: https://stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help You today. It's too late for me, but I would suggest you to just google "what compression formats allow inplace replacement". And if You **really** struggle with finding an answer, then, and only then come on any "stack" site.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not implemented in any compression format except of course in compressed file systems.

The reason is simple:  Data cannot be compressed at a fixed rate, so by changing the input data the output data can change in size.  If for example you have a string of 1000 zero-bytes first as input, these can be compressed perfectly (into 29 bytes, using gzip, for example).  If you now change them into 1000 bytes of random content (white noise), then they cannot be compressed at all (gzip typically produces 1023 bytes output then, due to adding some header bytes).

If we are talking about a combination of compression an packaging (like ZIP, TGZ or similar), this would mean to insert some more bytes in the middle of a file, hence, shifting all bytes after this spot to make place.  This shifting operation on the other hand isn't what current operating systems are prepared for.  (At least Neither Unix nor windows allows that.)  The result would be copying everything which comes after the spot to realize the shifting.  This isn't efficient and thus not feasible.

One could contrive a file format which allows for insertions which can be added to the end of the file, but I have never heard of such a thing.

If you use a compressed file system you can of course change any file therein, no matter its position.  And to send it as a single file you can send the contents of the block device it is stored in.

Have a look at the `fusecompress` file system for this task.  I think the project has been abandoned, but maybe you can find a working snapshot somewhere.